# Is the set $\mathbb C - \{z:: \Re z \le 0$ and $\Im z = -1\}$ simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Is the set:

$\mathbb C - \{z:: \Re z \le 0$ and $\Im z = -1\}$

a simply connected domain?

it looks like it is because any closed curve i can imagine can be shrunk to a point. is this right?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed simply connected. In fact it is even a star domain : if you define $z_0=1-i$, then for any $z\in \mathbb C \setminus \{z |\Re z \le 0 \text{ and }\Im z=-1\}$ the segment $\{z_0+t(z-z_0)|t\in [0,1]\}$ lies in $\mathbb C \setminus \{z |\Re z \le 0 \text{ and }\Im z=-1\}$. This implies that it is also contractible, and thus simply connected.